# Door jamb framing is out of plumb

Tags: doors, framing, door-frame, old-house, jamb

I'm remodeling our family room and will need to put flooring down. The front doorway needs to be reframed so the door sits above the floor.

The current jamb is a mess likely due to our old house's framing. They had to cut a pocket for the hinge to sit in so the door would be plumb.

Does anyone have any suggestions on improving this before I start putting in a new door jamb?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, plumb. Thanks

Comment: Is the door face out of plumb, or is the wall out of plumb?

Comment: It's the wall, unfortunately

Comment: Ouch!  Is the opposite wall out of plumb too???  And is this entire wall OOP, or just the part below the top of the door?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real fix is to re-sheetrock the wall with angled shims to make it plumb on the inside at least.  There is no practical way to straighten a wall's structure without rebuilding it.  I see new sheetrock on the left already, just do it some more.

Or you'll need to install the door angled in the new frame as they did previously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll consider shimming out the drywall.